# ExpandableListView getGroupView friom child control

Tags: android, listview, expandablelistview

In an Expandablelistview, I want to update the one of the groupview image based on the selected control in the childview, how to accomplish this ??
 basically 
 i want like this

```
public View  getChildview(int groupPosition,final int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView,ViewGroup parent)
{

  View Groupview=parent.getChildAt(groupPosition); ///but gives null when if scrolling the expandablelist

}
```

EDIT 
Below Code works me

```
public View getGroupView(ExpandableListView listView, int groupPosition) {
  long packedPosition = ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionForGroup(groupPosition);
  int flatPosition = listView.getFlatListPosition(packedPosition);
  int first = listView.getFirstVisiblePosition();
  return listView.getChildAt(flatPosition - first);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using OnChildClickListener and override onChildClick() and use this [code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30087894/2450000) in getting the parent view.

Comment: will try this, is there any way i can access listview in adapter class ?

Comment: One of the parameters in the onChildClick() provides you the listview of the adapter which is one of the reasons why I recommended it ;) Also, you set the OnChildClickListener on the activity/fragment where your ExpandableListview is instantiated, so you actually have an easy reference of it. (Forgot to mention the OnChildClickListener, will edit the question)

Comment: Thanks, i passed the reference..public ExpandListViewAdapter(Activity mActivity, ExpandableListView cmgListView) {
        this.mActivity = mActivity;
        this.mListView=cmgListView;
    }

Answer (score 0):

```
getGroupView() – Returns view for the list group header
getChildView() – Returns view for list child item
So u must create/inflate view in getChildView method
```

For more details: 
http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/